# Unexpected Indentation in Visual Studio Code with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation

the following code

```
accounts = f.get_sepa_accounts()

for account in accounts:
    print(account)
```

is throwing the following error:

```
>>>     print(account)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(account)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I just moved to Visual Studio Code, so no idea if this is a problem specific to the application. I tried 4 spaces and a tab already..Doesn't do anything.

Comment: How are you running your code? The fact that the error says "line 1" makes me suspicious that it isn't seeing the two lines previous to that one.

Comment: No reason this shouldn't work, did you try restarting Visual studio?
Does the error still occur when running your script in something other then Visual studio?

Comment: Weird, the restart did it...Thanks!

Comment: @user2252633 Glad the restart worked out for you! Visual studio gets grumpy at times. Id post it as a answer but I don't think its necessary, glad I could help solve the problem!

Comment: Seems to have to do with my hotkey Shift + Enter for running a file (was used to this from Jupyter). What is the correct hotkey for this? I wasn't able to find this in cheat sheets and so on..

Answer (score 9):

Update:- The more recent versions of VSCode don't seem to have this issue.

You have probably used tabs when indenting. You can check this by selecting the code. When selected the tabs are highlighted with a right pointing arrow in VS Code as shown in the image below:-

[image: Screenshot showing arrows for tabs and dots for spaces]

Notice the two arrows in the second line. See how the second line is error because of this.
You fix this by selecting the two tabs and pressing Ctrl+H. Replace with the right amount of spaces.

**In short replace tabs with spaces.**

Comment: This is an **unrelated problem** that is **not editor specific**, but caused by Python's syntax itself. It equally causes problems in source code files. The question is **specifically** about a problem that occurs **only when pasting the code into a REPL**.

Answer (score 5):

Press F1 and start typing 'Indentation to spaces' and you will be able to find
**'Convert Indentation to Spaces'** option, select and click enter.

Next time, mostly you just have to press F1 and enter because it is selected by default since you used it recently.

[image: F1 and enter]

Answer (score 1):

**Restart Visual Studio Code.**

Sometimes this can help.

Also ensure that you **choose the right linter** (CTRL + SHIFT + P > "Python: Select Linter" and choose f.e. **pylint**) before you restart.

Comment: restarting VScode solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because Visual Studio code seems to act up when using the triple ''' commenting out style rather than the more simple # commenting style

In the triple ''' commenting style you put the ''' at the start of the code or comments you want to comment out and then multiple lines later you can just put another ''' to end the comment

But, I've found that its just not worth the effort in Visual Studio Code to use
'''  because it often gets confused - especially if you are mixing in different
' and " in your code or using strings or other such things...

If you stick to # you'll find the error will go away...
at least until Visual Studio code fixes it (as of 17 April 2023 its still an issue)